# Why did Prosus NV's PE ratio fall so sharply?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation

Consider the historical P/E ratio of Prosus N.V. ADR (OTC markets: PROSY):

[image: PROSY historical P/E chart - YCharts]

(source: https://ycharts.com/companies/PROSY/pe_ratio)

[image: PROSY historical P/E chart - Gurufocus]

(source: https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/PROSY/data/pe-ratio)

Observations:

- At the end of March 2021, the P/E ratio to suddenly dropped from 40+ to around 25.
- At the end of September 2021, the P/E ratio suddenly dropped from 15+ to less than 7.

As far as I can tell, there was no abrupt change in the stock price over the past year:

[image: Google PROSY]

(source: Google)

What happened in the first and third quarters of 2021 that cause the P/E ratio to drop sharply?

Answer (score 1):

> Observations:
>
> - At the end of March 2021, the P/E ratio to suddenly dropped from 40+ to around 25.
>   -At the end of September 2021, the P/E ratio suddenly dropped from 15+ to less than 7.
>
> As far as I can tell, there was no abrupt change in the stock price
> over the past year:

So if P/E made a big move, but the price (p) didn't make a big move; that means that earnings (E) made a big move.

For example if price is $100 and earnings is $2.5 then P/E is 40. But if the earnings go to $4 but the price doesn't change the P/E drops to 25.

In reality there was a change in both P and E which resulted in the P/E moving from 40 to 25.

from the website you [linked to](https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/PROSY/data/pe-ratio):

> The price to earnings ratio is calculated by taking the current stock
> price and dividing it by the most recent trailing twelve-month
> earnings per share (EPS) number. The data is updated every 20 minutes
> during market hours.

you should expect jumps when Price is updated every 20 mintes, but Earnings updated every 3 months.

The clue was that the jumps occur quarterly.

Comment: What is the cause of the jump in earnings that did not move the price, leading to a lower and lower P/E ratio?

Comment: Maybe everybody knew what the jump was going to be and the jump was already factored into the price.